# Function finding substrings in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create an algorithm that takes a list of strings as a parameter. It prints every string in the list that is a substring of the one that precedes it.

Example of output I want for function `findSubStrs(lst)`:

```
findSubStrs(['hopefully','hope','hop','testing','test'])
hope
hop
test
```

What I have:

```
def findSubStrs(lst):

  for word in lst:
      for letter in word:
          print(letter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` to compare each element in the list with the one prior:

```
def find_substrs(li):
    return [y for x,y in zip(li,li[1:]) if y in x]

find_substrs(['hopefully','hope','hop','testing','test'])
Out[49]: ['hope', 'hop', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def find_substrings(array):
    def inner(prev, this):
        print(this) if this in prev else None
        return this
    reduce(inner, array)
find_substrings((['hopefully', 'hope', 'hop', 'testing', 'test'])
```

I could have done the `if`/`print` in two lines, but I was jealous of the brevity of @rioppi's solution `:P`